# ListProperty with GoogleAppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

How do I assign a ListProperty with Google App Engine?

```
    name = self.request.get("name")
    description = self.request.get("description")
    list = '''insert code here'''
```

I want list to work like a dictionary, is this possible with Google App Engine, if so, how:

[wordone : score; wordtwo : score; wordthree : score]

^I want the list property to store some data like this, how is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually won't be able to store a true dictionary as type in a `ListProperty` (it only supports datastore property types, of which `dict` is not one), so you won't be able to get the behavior you're looking for. Will all of the data be the same (i.e. each element represents a word score)? Assuming storing each word as its own property on the model doesn't make sense, one 'dirty' solution would be to make a `ListProperty` of type `str`, and then append the word and score as separate elements. Then, when you searched for a word in the list, you would return the value at the index position of the word + 1. That would looks something like:

```
class MyEntity(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  description = db.TextProperty()
  word_list = db.ListProperty()
```

You could then add words like:

```
new_entity = MyEntity()
new_entity.word_list = ['word1', 1, 'word2', 2, 'word3', 10]
```

You could then query for a particular entity and then examine its `word_list` property (a list), looking for your target word and returning the element one position after it.

---

**More convoluted suggestion**

However if that isn't an option, you could look into creating another model (let's say `WordScore`) that looked something like:

```
class WordScore(db.Model):
  word = db.StringProperty()
  score = db.IntegerProperty()
```

Then, whenever you needed to add a new score, you would create a `WordScore` instance, fill out the properties and then assign it to the proper entity. I haven't tested any of this, but the idea would be something like:

```
# Pull the 'other' entity (this would be your main class as defined above)
q = OtherEntity.all()
q.filter('name =', 'Someone')
my_entity = q.get()

# Create new score
ws = WordScore(parent=my_entity)
ws.word = 'dog'
ws.score = 2
ws.put()
```

You could then pull out the score for `dog` for 'Someone' by doing something like this (again, completely untested for now - be warned :) ):

```
# Get key of 'Someone'
q = OtherEntity.all()
q.filter('name =', 'Someone')
my_entity = q.get().key()

# Now get the score
ws = WordScore.all()
ws.filter('word = ', 'dog').ancestor(my_entity)
word_score = ws.get().score
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to [NDB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) and use the Pickle property:

> Value is a Python object (such as a list or a dict or a string) that is serializable using Python's pickle protocol; the Datastore stores the pickle serialization as a blob. Unindexed by default.

[NDB Properties](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties)

Then you can use it directly:

```
class table(ndb.Model):
    data_dict = ndb.PickleProperty(default = {})
```

then

```
dd = table()
dd.data_dict['word_one'] = "Some_Score"
```

Comment: +1 - need to do some more experimenting with NDB and this looks like a compelling reason to do so!